# Mongodb exception can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to group my mongodb query based on year, month, day.

My **data** is **stored** in **database as below** :

```
{
"installAt" : "2016-08-01T10:24:38.502Z",
"success" : true
"app" : "web"
}
```

**Query using which I am trying to achieve above** :

```
db.sampleCollection.aggregate(
       [
          {
            $group : {
               _id : { month: { $month: "$installAt" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$installAt" }, year: { $year: "$installAt" } },
               count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          }
       ]
    )
```

**But I am getting this error** :

```
 assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date",
        "code" : 16006,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date",
        "code" : 16006,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:244:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1149:12)
    at (shell):1:23
2016-12-07T19:48:25.541+0530 Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date",
        "code" : 16006,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

**One reason of this exception** may be(**I am not sure**) because

`"installAt" : "2016-08-01T10:24:38.502Z"`

**is not in mongodb date format but String**.

**If this is the problem, then one one way of solving this** is updating these fields to `ISODate` format e.g

`ISODate("2016-08-01T10:24:38.502Z")`

but due to certain reason I can't not modify my database at this time.

**Is their any way I can achieve grouping using above code or alternative code,
(without updating database)**

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is the problem. Your date is string.

i inserted a doc like

```
db.date1.insert(
{ "installAt" : new ISODate("2016-08-01T10:24:38.502Z"), 
"success" : true ,"app" : "web" })
```

and ran  your query

```
db.date1.aggregate(
       [
          {
            $group : {
               _id : { month: { $month: "$installAt" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$installAt" }, year: { $year: "$installAt" } },
               count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          }
       ]
    )
```

returns me

```
{ "_id" : { "month" : 8, "day" : 1, "year" : 2016 }, "count" : 1 }
```

> Now if you are not keen on recreating your collection and convert
>   installAt as date what you can do is you can change the field type
>   using the $type operator.
>
> a sample on how to do that is
>
> ```
> var cursor = db.date1.find(); 
> while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
>   var doc = cursor.next(); 
>   db.date1.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {installAt: new ISODate(doc.installAt) }});
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks for your help. your solution will work, but at current time due to some reason I can not update database

Comment: Your solution works but you didn't use the $type operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily acheive this by using ***[$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)*** to group the year and day of month.

```
db.sampleCollection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "year": {
                "$substr": ["$installAt", 0, 4]
            },
            "day": {
                "$substr": ["$installAt", 5, 2]
            }
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the following way, but this is not the only way

```
varcursor=db.sampleCollection.find({"installAt": { "$exists": true }});
while(cursor.hasNext()){
  vardoc=cursor.next();
  db.tempcollection.insert({ "_id": doc._id, "installAt": newISODate(doc.installAt), "success": doc.success, "app": doc.web })
};

db.tempCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month: {
          $month: "$installAt"
        },
        day: {
          $dayOfMonth: "$installAt"
        },
        year: {
          $year: "$installAt"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In this approach we are creating a new collection "tempcollection", since the requirement is to not modify/update the existing collection. We can drop this tempcollection once we are done with our operations.